# How to treat system of linear first order differential equations with trigonometric function coefficients?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

I'm having trouble solving the following IVP:
$$x_1^\prime = -x_1\tan t + 3\cos^2t$$
$$x_2^\prime = x_1 + x_2\tan t + 2\sin t$$
where $x_1(0) = 4$ and $x_2(0) = 0$.

I'm not sure what to do when the coefficients are trigonometric functions. I've dealt with constant coefficients and we just learned reduction of order, but I'm confused about how to approach this problem.

Comment: Are you sure the first equation shouldn't have $x_2$ in it somewhere? Otherwise, it's just a first order linear equation whose solution you can compute exactly.

Comment: @David H I just checked again and there is no $x_2$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The first equation is a first-order linear equation in $t$ and $x_1$ with the integrating factor $\sec t$. Thus $x_1(t)=3\sin t\cos t+c_1\cos t$. Substituting this into the second one you will get another linear equation in $t$ and $x_2$ with integrating factor $\cos t$. I guess you can continue from this point.

Comment: Are you sure about that $x_1(t)$?